# char representation clojure

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, lisp

How can I represent a char (character) in clojure?

Also I would like an example to test it using the char? function

```
(println (char? 1))
(println (char? (char 'a')))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a backslash for representing an individual character. For instance:

```
(char? \a)
```

returns `true`